# Encounter`perf`'s "Permission error mapping pages." when running `perf` on centos with multicores?

Tags: linux, perf

when I run perf record, eg.

```
perf record -F 99 -p <pid> -g -o perf.data --call-graph dwarf -- sleep 120
```

it gives me

```
Permission error mapping pages.
Consider increasing /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb,
or try again with a smaller value of -m/--mmap_pages.
(current value: 4294967295,0)
```

but I got 516 after I run

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb
```

and I tried -m some size but it did not work, I was wondering what was wrong?

My kernel version is 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.v1.2.x86_64

Is there a known issue with running perf